# php form post values not working properly

Tags: php, html

If i do the normal calculation means its working, but if i pass the value from form means its not working kindly please help me.

For example:

```
echo $a=(1.5 * 10E-8) - (4.6 * 10E-8);
```

Result : -3.1E-7 but its not working when I get the values from form.

For example:

```
echo $m3=($_REQUEST['m3']); echo "<br>"; \* m3 value getting from form */
echo $m2=($_REQUEST['m2']); echo "<br>"; \* m2 value getting from form */
echo $b=$m3-$m2;
```

> Result : -3.1

I need the result fully with that scientific notation.

Comment: You will likely need to force change the variable type. It will be posted as a string by default.

Comment: This is because all values passed from a form are strings. You have to convert those strings to the correct type for your calculations to work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not having read the manual.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576927/2943403

Answer (score 1):

You need to `cast` the form's post values into `float`

```
echo $m3=(float)($_REQUEST['m3']); echo "<br>"; \* m3 value getting from form */
echo $m2=(float)($_REQUEST['m2']); echo "<br>"; \* m2 value getting from form */
echo $b=$m3-$m2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Form working properly. You just need to always echo your result in scientific notation and remove * from form inputs:

```
$a = '1.510E-8';
$b = '4.610E-8';
echo sprintf('%e', $a-$b);
//result: -3.100000e-8
```

Comment: echo $a=(5.4 * 10E-8) - (9.8 * 10E-9); echo "<br>"; Result : 4.42E-7

Comment: if i remove * from form inputs means am getting wrong output dude...

Comment: $a = '1.510E-8';
$b = '4.610E-8';
echo sprintf('%e', $a-$b);
//result: 1.04x10 E -8

Comment: V G see my last comment, like that only i need the result.

Comment: I suggest you to replace 'e' to 'x10e' in result and you will got it.

Comment: ok V G good and nice.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Form values return strings or arrays of strings. You need to cast them into an numeric type, if you would like to do calculations with them..

For example:

```
$m3 = intval($_REQUEST["m3"]);
```